# Is there an equivalente to UNIQUE in Google Sheets that does not separate letter cases?

Tags: google-sheets

For example, by using UNIQUE, I would have four items in a unique list, because they have differente usage of letter cases.  Is there an instruction that does not care about letter cases and considers only one for the unique list?

Hello
hello
HELLO
HeLLo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try

```
=index(proper(unique(lower(A2:A6))))
```

or, if you don't need the 'proper case'

```
=index(unique(lower(A2:A6)))
```

(Change range to suit)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `filter` to bring back the first instance of each word (case-insensitive):

```
=arrayformula(filter(A2:A,countifs(A2:A,A2:A,row(A2:A),"<="&row(A2:A))=1))
```

[image]

For the last instance, adapt to:

```
=arrayformula(filter(A2:A,countifs(A2:A,A2:A,row(A2:A),">="&row(A2:A))=1))
```